# Trigger preview mode by passing data from one controller to another

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to trigger a preview mode from one controller onto another using angular service but can't get the final step done. I am trying to get the url from the passed parameter into that ng-src in SideMenuCtrl. Not sure how to do it so that it would happen dynamically.

I have seen a few similar threads but not with a final end result like mine because I am trying to eventually display an image on the screen.

How would I link the passed parameter advert to vm.previewImage/.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])

.service('appState', function() {
    this.data = {
      preview: {
        enabled: false,
        advert: ''
      }
    };
    
    this.previewAdvert = function(advert) {
      //flick the inPreview variable
      this.data.preview = {
        enabled: !this.data.preview.enabled,
        advert: advert
      }
    }
    
})

.controller('SideMenuCtrl', function(appState) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.preview = appState.data.preview;
})

.controller('ContentCtrl', function(appState) {
   var vm = this;
   vm.advertUrl = 'http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-vXmHgrrk4ic/UpTbgBkp8eI/AAAAAAAAFjQ/ajBQ9WvwNUc/s1600/gloomy-stripes-dark-background-tile.jpg';
   
   vm.previewAdvert = function() {
     console.log('preview/stop preview');
     appState.previewAdvert(vm.advertUrl);
   }
   
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
  <body>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    
    <div ng-controller="SideMenuCtrl as vm">
      <div class="ads" ng-if="vm.preview.enabled">
        <img ng-src="{{vm.previewImage}}">
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div ng-controller="ContentCtrl as vm">
      <label for="adInput">Advert URL</label>
      <input type="url" id="adInput" ng-model="vm.advertUrl"></input>
      <button ng-mouseenter="vm.previewAdvert()" ng-mouseleave="vm.previewAdvert()">Preview</button>
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your service is shared all right between your controllers. However I noticed that with AngularJs properties from the controller are not always updated when their value change.

When this happens, you can use a function that returns your value and use the function call instead your value in your views. This way, updates are detected.

(NOTE: I moved the "SideMenuCtrl" div under because with the image appearing, the button was not hovered anymore, causing "mouseleave" to be called and that produced a flickering)

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])

.service('appState', function() {
    this.data = {
      preview: {
        enabled: false,
        advert: ''
      }
    };
    
    this.previewAdvert = function(advert) {
      //flick the inPreview variable
      this.data.preview = {
        enabled: !this.data.preview.enabled,
        advert: advert
      }
    }
    
})

.controller('SideMenuCtrl', function(appState) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.getPreviewImage = function(){
        return appState.data.preview.advert;
    };
    vm.isPreviewEnabled = function(){
        return appState.data.preview.enabled;
    };
})

.controller('ContentCtrl', function(appState) {
   var vm = this;
   vm.advertUrl = 'http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-vXmHgrrk4ic/UpTbgBkp8eI/AAAAAAAAFjQ/ajBQ9WvwNUc/s1600/gloomy-stripes-dark-background-tile.jpg';
   
   vm.previewAdvert = function() {
     console.log('preview/stop preview');
     appState.previewAdvert(vm.advertUrl);
   }
   
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
  <body>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    
    <div ng-controller="ContentCtrl as vm">
      <label for="adInput">Advert URL</label>
      <input type="url" id="adInput" ng-model="vm.advertUrl"></input>
      <button ng-mouseenter="vm.previewAdvert()" ng-mouseleave="vm.previewAdvert()">Preview</button>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="SideMenuCtrl as vm">
      <div class="ads" ng-if="vm.isPreviewEnabled()">
        <img ng-src="{{vm.getPreviewImage()}}">
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Will that not call vm.isPreviewEnabled like every few seconds though?

Comment: you can add a `console.log` inside the function if you want to verify it. It is called several times, but when there is a change only, not continuously. I'm not a specialist in angular source code, but they may set listeners to watch that, maybe it's when the DOM is changed, or things in the controller. Anyway you don't have to worry about that for performance in this kind of code, all should go smoothly unless you have millions of elements in your view